# Multiple CommandButtons updates with similar

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to simplify my macro for `CommandButton` on worksheet.
I got loads of buttons which should change depending on cell data.
If I write line by line

```
CommandButton25.Caption = Range("C29").Value
CommandButton26.Caption = Range("C30").Value
```

or

```
ActiveSheet.CommandButton27.Caption = Range("c31").Value
```

It works. But if I try to use something like

```
For i = 28 To 40

ActiveSheet("CommandButton" & i).Caption = Range("c31").Value

Next i
```

Problem is most likely with (`CommandButton` & `i`).

I have a similar macro for `Label` on user form.

```
For i = 1 To 40
Desk("Label" & i).Caption = ActiveCell(4 + i, 3)
Next i
```

which works perfectly.

If it was just for 40 lines I would probably leave it, but there are more buttons on user forms and other sheets.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should loop in shapes, and that is your problem, I mean like:

```
For i = 28 To 40
  ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton" & i).Caption=Range("c31").Value
Next i
```

If this does not work, then I think you should just paste your code onto a blank Excel sheet, then split the cells like:

- A1 : CommandButton
- B1: 25
- C1: .Caption = Range("C29").Value
- D1: =A1&B1&C1

Then you can just pull the whole thing down, copy column D's contents in a notepad and paste it as code, and problem solved. Not very elegant, but it will work  :)
Good luck!

Comment: Not working, RT error: Object does not support ...  Non elegant method doesn't solve my problem :\ (or how to set B1 as range 1 to 40?)

Comment: You type 1 in b1 and 2 in b2 then select b1:b2 and just pull it down dragged by the corner. Then you will have an ascending column of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the specified 'control' objects within UserForms, like this:

```
For i 28 To 40
    myUserForm.Controls("CommandButton" & i).Caption = Range("C31").Value
Next i
```

You can loop through the command buttons on worksheets using the below:

```
Sub cb_loop()
    Dim i As Byte
    For i = 28 To 48
        Sheets("sheet1").Shapes("CommandButton" & i).DrawingObject.Object.Caption = Range("C31").Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I saw you mention userforms so thought you were talking about them. I've updated the answer to include looping through worksheet command buttons.